# Returns the wrong character in SubString method

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I am new to JS, i have tried the below code,

```
var str = "\">2\""
var res = str.substring(2,1);
```

**Return:** `>`

**Expected:** `2`

I have checked this by below code,

```
var str = "\">2\""
var res = str.substring(2);
```

**Return:** `"2\"`

**Expected:** `"2\"`

Please let me know if i misunderstand anything, why it returns `>` instead of `2`. In C# it works correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Actually you are doing to it incorrect in case 1

When you do

```
str.substring(2,1);
```

That actually means

```
str.substring(1,2);
```

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

> If indexStart is greater than indexEnd, then the effect of substring() is as if the two arguments were swapped; for example, str.substring(1, 0) == str.substring(0, 1).

Since the char at 1,2 is `>`, you getting the same.

However when you do

```
str.substring(2);
```

It actually equals to

```
 str.substring(2, str.length-1);
```

> If indexEnd is omitted, substring() extracts characters to the end of the string.

Comment: Alternatively use `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

javascript substring function will work like this

**string.substring(start, end)**

```
var str = "\">2\""
var res = str.substring(2,1);
```

in this case
**If "start" is greater than "end", it will swap the two arguments:**

so answer will **>** only

and in second case

```
var str = "\">2\""
var res = str.substring(2);
```

**Begin the extraction at position 2, and extract the rest of the string:**

so answer will **2"**

this link will help you for more imformation [javascript substring function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 0):

substring(2,1) gives you only the character at the 2nd position only,
Where as substring(2) returns string from the 2nd position till the end of the string.